# Moving database format from Chrome to Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, firefox-addon

I have a Chrome extension that stores data with a json string in a localStorage variable. I'm trying to create a version of this extension for firefox. But in firefox localStorage doesn't seem to work for extensions.

Is there anyway to simply store a json string persistantly in firefox? Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't addons have native persistent storage? You know.. using the files that load the addon.. You could just write to them.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Which files do you mean?

Comment: Maybe he means just using the folder that your addon is in. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/File_I%2F%2FO#Getting_special_files But since most addons are now xpi's instead of folders, I don't think this is the best approach.

Comment: Another thing you can do is just store it in a preference. I know some addons do that. Seems like a misuse of the preferences system to me but there are worse crimes...

Answer (score 2):

If you're use Firefox's [Addon SDK](https://jetpack.mozillalabs.com/sdk/1.0b5/docs/dev-guide/welcome.html) to do your extension, you can use the built-in [simple-storage module](https://jetpack.mozillalabs.com/sdk/1.0b5/docs/packages/addon-kit/docs/simple-storage.html). It exposes a `storage` object that your code can treat like a regular javascript object, but Firefox will store it persistently for you.

A simplified example looks like:

```
// load the simple storage module
var storage = require('simple-storage').storage;

// write a value to the key "bacon"
storage.bacon = JSON.stringify({"tasty": "is bacon"});

// do stuff, retrieve the value later and pass it to a function
eat(storage.bacon);
```

Even in later sessions, the value in storage.bacon will be available to the extension.